# How to get city name from parameter variable for Google Map API

Tags: google-maps

I am using this function: `getDirection(glat,glon,acity)` Using this function I have to draw a route from a city to the glat and glong [latitude and longitude] position. I was finished with everything but I dont know how to set variable acity as origin.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var default_latitude=22.5936840;//12.9715987;
var default_longitude=78.962880;//77.5945627;
var myOptions = 
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(default_latitude,default_longitude),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapp"),myOptions);


var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glon);

$('#mapDiv1').modal({closeClass: "mapCloseImg1"});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));

var request = {
  origin: [WANT TO PUT ACITY AS ORIGIN BUT DONT KNOW HOW]
  destination:latlng,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
}); 
}
```

Comment: What you need is to use Reverse Geocode.
See this docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: simply use `origin:acity`

Comment: @red_alert: origin and destination also accept strings, the directionsService will do the geocoding automatically.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks a lot sir ,,, i think that it will be a very long process